# What does it mean, during the Grand Unified Epoch, that matter fluctuated between lepton and baryon states?

Tags: leptons, baryons, grand-unification

My understanding of leptons and baryons is that leptons are an elementary particle, while baryons are a composite particle. Can someone explain to me what particles fluctuating between lepton and baryon states looks like? What species of lepton are fluctuating into what species of baryon, and by what force?

Comment: You better look up the definition of baryons. My understanding is that baryons are the green-colored $SU(3)$ singlets frequenting the bars around Saint Patrick's Day.

Comment: please give a link for your statement.about fluctuations.